# Problemas al referenciar un Objeto

Tags: android, android-fragment, clase, object, null

Estoy llamando a una clase que ya he utilizado, lo he instanciado y en mi fragmento Login si corre normal pero en mi fragmento Cliente_Visit me sale un error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android, PID: 13567
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.M_Menu$Time_Stop.Sen_Msg_Function(sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.Herramt_Cli.Clas_ArrayList)' on a null object reference
                      at sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.AsisTec.Frg_Client_Visit.Carg_Formulario(Frg_Client_Visit.java:87)
                      at sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.AsisTec.Frg_Client_Visit.onCreateView(Frg_Client_Visit.java:196)
```

1.- De esta manera llamo en mi fragmento de Login (sale correctamente):

A través del Clas_ArrayList llamo a (List_Mens); que es lo que quiero y abajo lo dejo en el código)

```
M_Menu.Time_Stop Tim;//asi llamo a la clase en la parte superior



 Logi.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(VerificacionUsuario()){
                    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Time_Stop 3 Carg_Verificar_User">
                    Clas_ArrayList List_Mens = new Clas_ArrayList();
                    List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato("Datos");//Titulo  0
                    List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato(Cls_Let.Get_Nombre_Formulario());//Formulario  1
                    List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato("Carg_Verificar_Acceso");//Funcion  2
                    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Set_User">
                    ArrayList<Object> Set_User=new ArrayList<>();
                    Set_User.add(Cls_Let.Get_String_Null_Mayu(CodUser));
                    Set_User.add("FR0009");//Cod Formulario//para el permiso de fechas
                    // </editor-fold>
                    List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato(Set_User);//Datos  3
                    List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato(Get_List_Access("Carg_Verificar_Acceso",
                            "Logeandote para entrar al sistema"));//Acceso  4
                    List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato(CodUser);//Cod Usuario 5
                    // </editor-fold>
                    Tim.Sen_Msg_Function ( List_Mens );
                    ShowProgressBar () ;
                }
            }
        } );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Y acá quiero llamar la misma clase pero en mi fragmento Client_Visit:(no sale)

```
M_Menu.Time_Stop Tim;//asi llamo a la clase en la parte superior


 Clas_ArrayList List_Mens = new Clas_ArrayList();
        List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato("Datos");//Titulo  0
        List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato(Cls_Let.Get_Nombre_Formulario());//Formulario  1
        List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato("Carg_Permiso_Form");//Funcion  2
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Per_Form">
        ArrayList<Object> Per_Form = new ArrayList<>();
        Per_Form.add(List_User.Get_Dat_StrxObj(2));//Cod User
        Per_Form.add(CodFormu);//Cod Formulario
        // </editor-fold>
        List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato(Per_Form);//Datos  3
        List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato(Get_List_Access("Carg_Permiso_Form",
                "cargando los eventos que tiene este usuario"));//Acceso  4
        List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato(List_User.Get_Dat_StrxObj(2));//Cod Usuario 5
        List_Mens.Set_ArrayLst_Dato("Cargando Permisos");//Mensaje Jprog 6
        // </editor-fold>
        Tim.Sen_Msg_Function ( List_Mens );
        Tim.Time_Stop_Init(15);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Hago exactamente lo mismo, los mismos pasos y no entiendo por que el error.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gracias por la ayuda y si, encontré el problema, lo que pasaba es que estaba tratando de llamar a una clase y en una parte si daba por que a traves de un Drawer yo le pasaba el metodo directamente pero en el otro no me cogía por que estaba ya fuera... a lo que voy es que mi solucion fue publicar mi metodo que estaba utilizando y volverlo estatico para que sea una variable global.

1.-(en el Main activity-- e principal donde nace)
public static Time_Stop Tim;

2.- (en la clase donde lo quiero jalar)
 M_Menu.Time_Stop Tim=M_Menu.Tim;

(con esto le estoy diciendo que coja el metodo desdes el menu principal)

Answer (score 0):

Ese error es ocurre cuanto estas intentando referenciar hacia un objeto que no existe, es decir, cuando intentas mostrar un valor i/o resultado en algún `TextView` o `ListView` y el mismo no ha sido creado o el `id` es incorrecto, debes revisar los llamados a las View que haces y ver que estén todas creadas y las mismas sean correctas.